# How insert a custom shape in imported external dynamic text in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible insert an arrow or something like this in the imported external text in flash.
Something like this:

[image]

Comment: look at TextField's htmlText property and try something like: `yourTextInstance.htmlText = '<img src="yourImage.jpg"/>text next to an image';`

Answer (score 1):

With

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.htmlText = "<img src='../image.gif'>" + externalText;
```

you can embed custom images in your TextField.

[See Adobe documentation for more.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText)

---

Another way is to use special characters. In Windows: Open Character Map by clicking the Start button, clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, clicking System Tools, and then clicking Character Map. Than copy-paste special characters to your code:

```
textField.htmlText = "► " + externalText + "♫♪♫";
```

Comment: But I want to use this many times in different places in my text. Is it possible  with more details describe for me, please. I want when user click on it, appears some text and when click on the text, disappear the text and appears the shape.

Comment: Hey this is good idea,thank you. But how I manipulate with this as a instance object in actionscript for own mean that described above?

Comment: @Amir you should accept this answer if it allows you to resolve the original question, if you have further questions you should attempt to solve them yourself then post back your attempts and specific issue.  SO is not a place to get other people to do work for you it is a place for questions and answers from which we can all benefit.  You should be able to set the htmlText from any function that has visibility of the textField (where that instance is in scope).  If what I'm saying doesn't make sense, Google some of the words that don't fit to you.

Comment: When an answer do not solve my problem why should accept it? I am not going to other people do my work, I'm looking for a solution. Perhaps because of my poor English I couldn't explain clearly my issue. Thank for your GOOD IDEA!!!